# blank page on form submit codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Every time I try to submit my form it just goes to a blank page. I have tried enabling error reporting but that does not come up with anything. Below is my MVC

**Model**

```
public function create($email, $password)
{
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|valid_email|xss_clean|is_unique[user.email]');
    if ($this->form_validation->run()== false) {
        return false;
    }
        $result = $this->db->insert('user', [
            'email' => $email, 
            'password' => sha1($password . HASH_KEY)
        ]);
            if($this->db->affected_rows()>0)
        {
            redirect(base_url().'admin/view_user');
        } 
}
```

**View**

```
public function create($email, $password)
{
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|valid_email|xss_clean|is_unique[user.email]');
    if ($this->form_validation->run()== false) {
        return false;
    }
        $result = $this->db->insert('user', [
            'email' => $email, 
            'password' => sha1($password . HASH_KEY)
        ]);
            if($this->db->affected_rows()>0)
        {
            redirect(base_url().'admin/view_user');
        } 
}
```

**Controller**

```
public function create_user ()
    {
        $email = $this->input->post('email');
        $password = $this->input->post('password');

        $this->load->model('Users_model');
        $this->Users_model->create($email, $password);
    }
```

Comment: I submitted an answer the will help. But I will try to see if I can get a more good code, give us your form, I will rearrange everything since I think your usage of controller/model/view mixes up :)

Comment: I think you have copied the same code for model and view both by mistake... @David

Comment: i think you have space on your files... trim the space and try

Comment: Yes he did it by mistake, but his coding is still not so much in the right track with respect to MVC, I have given my code and hope it helps him to understand more :)

Comment: Does your form submit url have IP address in it? if it does you need to set your base url in config.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**VIEW**

```
<form action="<?php echo base_url();?>/controller/insert_user" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" required>
<input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required>
<input type="submit" value="submit>
</form>
```

**CONTROLLER** *Updated*

```
 function insert_user()
{
    $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    $email = $this->input->post('email');
    $password = $this->input->post('password');

    //Set your validations here

    if ($this->form_validation->run()== false) 
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
         $data = array('email'=>$email,
                       'password'=>sha1($password . HASH_KEY)
                      );
         $this->Users_model->insert_user_to_db($data);
         redirect(base_url().'admin/view_user');
     }
}
```

**MODEL**

```
function insert_user_to_db($data)
{
    $this->db->insert('YOUR_TABLE',$data);
}
```

View should be the HTML
Controller should contain all the functions you want
Model should only deal with the database

and it looks like you want the email to be unique in the database, you can also do so by putting a code that gets all emails from the database, then if one matches, it fails again. you put that in the //set your validation here

Let me know if you need more help

GOODLUCK!!!

Comment: the redirect is in the model

Comment: Yea that's wrong in terms of MVC, I'll make this clearer in a minute i'll just code it

Comment: Still goes to a blank page

Comment: Kindly add your view since it's missing from your post

Comment: Also post your new controller, I think form validation is the one causing the error here. @David

Comment: That's not really what I meant but i just accepted it. @David what I mean is did you add form validations? Or is that exactly what you're using right now? The one i made

Comment: I added the form validation and found that the users model was not loaded. All seems to be working well now

Comment: @David , Okay good. I though you had that in the constructor. Goodluck coding